# meaning of createObject(Point.getClsid())

Tags: arcobjects

What actually does the `createObject(Point.getClsid())` do?Does it create a new Point Object,and return the class id of the `Point`.Does it mean that each point created will have the same class id.

I went through ESRI documentation but all it said was Identify class ID for an object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is related to COM.

> A [CLSID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms691424%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is a globally unique identifier that identifies a COM
>   class object. If your server or container allows linking to its
>   embedded objects, you need to register a CLSID for each supported
>   class of objects.

In .NET though, it seems like these are now being called "progIDs", for example in the [CreateObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7t9k08y5%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) documentation.

It looks like .getClsid is a static (or shared) method in this case.  However I don't see one for the  ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.PointClass in C#.